# Are there good bounds on the sum of inverse degrees for a graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request, analytic-combinatorics

I'm looking for any literature on the sum $\sum\limits_{v\in V} \frac{1}{\deg(v)}$, but when I look for inverted degree sum, not much comes up about this specifically.  I figure that it is either old and common knowledge, or nobody has looked at properties of this sum before.  Can you point me in some directions for literature?  Books, papers, arXiv articles, and websites are all welcome!

Comment: Does this sum have any "nice" properties that would justify an interest in it?

Comment: @IvanNeretin A variant of it gives you a way of bounding the independence number of a graph (Caro Wei Theorem). There the sum is over $\frac{1}{1 + d(v)}$ however. It also seems like a reasonable way of measuring the number of low degree vertices in a graph?

Comment: A local version is good as a centrality measure for detecting connection to low degree vertices.  Taking $N(v)$ to the the set of neighbors of vertex $v$, the sum $\sum\limits_{u \in N(v)} \frac{1}{\deg(u)}$ seems to be useful in determining how valuable certain vertices are to keeping the graph connected.